# KineticJS: Disable dragging

Tags: javascript, canvas, draggable, kineticjs

I need to find out a way to disable dragging shapes in KineticJS

For example, I have a Circle with the `draggable` option enabled.

I want to disable dragging this circle if the shiftKey is pressed down and I would like to handle this case in a different way.

Here's an example of what I would like to do: http://jsfiddle.net/nL3kb/

Is it possible somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several options.  One thing you could do is make a group draggable and add the circle to the group.  On mousedown, if shift was pressed, you can cancel the event propagation such that the group drag and drop functionality is canceled.

http://jsfiddle.net/SyMRJ/

You could also add logic that toggles off drag and drop using draggable(false) whenever the shift key is pressed down

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks! I'm not very happy with Grouping solution, but it seems to work for me

Comment: UPDATE - you can now cancel live KineticJS drag and drop operations at anytime using .setDraggable(false)

Comment: I've just experimented with this in Kinetic.js 5.1.0: It looks like setDraggable(true/false) in the mousedown event handler (depending on keys down) is the only _reliable_ way to prevent dragging from happening. dragstart / dragmove are too late (dragging is already happening), and cancelBubble / stopPropagation() in mousedown don't work.